# issue with http connector while creating dataset in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

http connector is not available in the list of data store available while creating dataset in azure data factory, could you please help  what to do here?
[ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyCQH.png)

i tried creating dataset but it is not working , but it is showing for other people, do i need to enable any settings?

Comment: can you please provide more details? such as your sample code or error message

Comment: please check above hyper link, when i was creating dataset for copy activity it is not showing connector

Comment: It seems as intermittent issue. Can you check once it is visible now in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

If HTTP is not available in dataset option, you can create HTTP linked service and then create a dataset for that linked service. To create a HTTP linked service in ADF,

- Click  **Manage** tab , then select **Linked Services** and then select **+New**

[image]

- Select the **http connector** in the linked service

[image]

- Enter the URL, Authentication and then click **create** to create http linked service.
- Once linked service is created, create one of the below datasets.

Avro format, Binary format, Delimited text format, Excel format, JSON format, ORC format, Parquet format, XML format.

These are all the supported datasets for `http` connector.